# exchange server mail forward

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange, exchange-2007

I would like to forward an e-mail address, like info@mycompany.com to our 2 webmasters on our exchange server.
But i can't find a good way to do this, i can add info@ as e-mail address to a user but only to one of them.

The only whey i can get it to work is to create a user 'info' and forward his mail to the 2 webmasters.

Is this the only way to do this? I've worked with other mail servers in the past and with most of them you would have the possibility to create an virtual mailbox like an alias or a forwarding adres.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a distribution group and add the two webmasters (either their contacts or their user accounts) to it.

[Link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb125256%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx)

Comment: you beat me to it by 30 seconds, Holo.

Comment: @joe hahaha. Fastest gun indeed :)

Answer (score 2):

Create a Distribution Group with the email address info@mycompany.com and add the webmasters as members of the group.